# Code after ajax (code) block needs a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I had a long question along with my complete code but now it is shorter one.

```
  function showRecord(tbl) {
    myDataTable.fnDestroy();
    $.ajax(
    {
        data: "tableName=" + tbl,
        url: "showTable.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) { $("#example").html(data); }
    });
    alert('I get desired output as long as I do not comment/remove this alert');
    myDataTable = $('#example').dataTable();
}
```

**BUT** if i just comment the `alert` I do not get data from database

If I do not use `$('#example').dataTable();` (a jquery plugin for pagination from [datatables.net](http://datatables.net) ) then code works fine without alert.

```
function showRecord(tbl) {
    //myDataTable.fnDestroy();
    $.ajax(
    {
        data: "tableName=" + tbl,
        url: "showTable.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) { $("#example").html(data); }
    });
  //alert('I get desired output as long as I do not comment/remove this alert');
  //myDataTable = $('#example').dataTable();
}
```

I need to know why alert is necessary in first sample of code. If it causes delay, why delay is necessary here and how to achieve this without using `alert`

Comment: `alert` creates a delay. Try to log with `console.log()` instead.

Comment: Thanks I do. But how is it possible in a line be line executed language to do some other thing while alert is being shown?

Comment: No its not working. But yes a silent alternative to alert can be a solution

Comment: It's possible when you use AJAX, the request will continue as long as you see the alert-window.

Comment: When a browser loads a page Javascript is executed line by line, but the browser does a lot of things parallel. The whole network traffic is loading parallel. So AJAX could be a problem. Images might not been loaded. DOM might not be ready...

Comment: Yes I think ajax would be the problem but as for as page load is concerned. I think my page is loaded only once after that when i am calling ajax to include a php file to get data from database at that time there occurs no page refresh and that is why i am using ajax

Comment: With the guidance of you people, I have almost found the problem and updated my question and shown the exact location of problem. But still have been unable to fix it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax calls are asynchronous. In the first block of code (if there is no `alert`) ajax call get executed and then immediately after that (before server responds) this line executes:

```
myDataTable = $('#example').dataTable();
```

and since server did not return result yet `$('#example')` is empty. You can put it it like this:

```
function showRecord(tbl) {
    myDataTable.fnDestroy();
    $.ajax(
    {
        data: "tableName=" + tbl,
        url: "showTable.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#example").html(data);
            myDataTable = $('#example').dataTable();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. Problem was already solved by @ek_ny Thanks to him. But you answered complete before others so cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
 function showRecord(tbl) {

        //myDataTable.fnDestroy();
        $.ajax(
        {
            data: "tableName=" + tbl,
            url: "showTable.php",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) { 
                $("#example").html(data);
                myDataTable = $('#example').dataTable(); }
        });
      //alert('I get desired output as long as I do not comment/remove this alert');
      //
    }
```